# JavaFX: Layout problem with BorderPane - bug or user error?

Tags: javafx, javafx-11

I am experiencing a strange behaviour with a FlowPane within (the center of) a BorderPane. [image: Example]

If I enlarge the width of the window or reduce it, everything is fine. It is just a narrow width +- 5 pixels that causes this effect. Code to reproduce:

```
public class LayoutBugTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TextField tf1 = new TextField("");
        TextField tf2 = new TextField("");
        TextField tf3 = new TextField("");
        tf1.setPrefColumnCount(20);
        tf2.setPrefColumnCount(10);
        tf3.setPrefColumnCount(10);     
        FlowPane flow = new FlowPane(10,10, tf1,tf2,tf3);
        
        BorderPane box = new BorderPane();
        box.setTop(new Label("Heading"));
        box.setCenter(flow);
        box.setStyle("-fx-border-width: 2px; -fx-border-color: black; -fx-border-radius: 1em; -fx-padding: 5px;");
        
        VBox anyLayout = new VBox(5, new Label("Before"), box, new Label("After"));
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(anyLayout);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

Did I miss something or is this a layout bug?

Comment: @matt hmm .. not entirely certain: there _is_ enough vertical space (provided we resize the window , borderLayout should report its increased pref and vbox should adjust the layout accordingly. Looks like a bug in one of the managers to me ..

Comment: @kleopatra "borderLayout should report its increased pref and vbox should adjust the layout accordingly." I agree, the work around I suggested makes it so the VBox just expands the BorderLayout regardless of the content.

Comment: Letting the BorderPane grow helps circumvent the problem in this example, since the contents won't reach the bottom border in this case. But often enough the intention is, that the content in the BorderPane only used the space required and it is always then that this problem occurs.

Comment: By the way: replacing the BorderPane with a VBox for layout and the problem is gone. It seems related to the BorderPane.

Comment: @taranion I see weirdness without the BorderPane: have the border around the flowPane, add it directly to the vbox, add button to decrease stage width by a single pixel, make sure there's enough vertical space, size width to just big enough for having the fields in two lines, decrease - at one point, the "after" label is shown inside the border of the flowPane while the fields are still in two rows. It's just a single pixel, next the fields are shown in three rows and the after label is below the flowPane. Maybe a rounding error, some incorrect snapXX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be an odd bug. I added some debugging information.

```
scene.widthProperty().addListener(evt ->{
        System.out.println( "box: " + box.prefHeight(anyLayout.getWidth()) + ", " + box.minHeight(anyLayout.getWidth()) + ", " + box.getHeight() );
        System.out.println( "flow: " + flow.prefHeight(box.getWidth()) + ", " + flow.minHeight(box.getWidth()) + ", " + flow.getHeight());

    });
```

When the program is started. The two fields narrow fields are side by side, and the preferred sizes are:

> box: 95.0, 95.0, 95.0
> flow: 64.0, 64.0, 64.0

As we decrease the width of the window the FlowPane switches orientation, but it's minimum and preferred sizes don't change.

> box: 95.0, 95.0, 95.0
> flow: 64.0, 64.0, 101.0

When we decrease further and the layout looks good again.

> box: 132.0, 132.0, 132.0
> flow: 101.0, 101.0, 101.0

So it appears BorderPane is using the correct width for the FlowPane to "layout" but it is using the incorrect width when requesting the preferred height. eg

```
flow.prefHeight(box.getWidth() - 14);
```

That pref. height follows the actual height of the FlowLayout. 14 from the padding and the border.

Comment: interesting .. (minor nit-pick: in fx the postfix is _Pane_, not _Layout_ :)

Comment: Swing habits, it also makes it hard when searching for the docs/issues. :D

Comment: I feared that it would be a bug. Oh well, it can be worked around.

Comment: *cough .. one of you might consider reporting it. A nice example, a thorough description and a workaround would make an ideal issue :)